# dbt run fails if there is a typo in a non-selected model

Tags: production-environment, dbt

We are trying to set up dbt as our main transform tool in a production environment (1000+ models), and have recently noticed a behavior that we see as dangerous. Thus, we are asking ourselves if there is a workaround to bypass it.

Let's say we want to run only one dbt model named `model_1`. So we simply select it with `dbt run --select model_1`. But it happens that there is a typo in `model_354` definition. Let me clarify that `model_1` and `model_354` are completely unrelated and do not share dependencies. But dbt first tries to compile **every model**, finds the typo in `model_354`, and in that very moment the `dbt run` command is aborted, no matter it was calling a model not related in any way to the one with the typo.

Now let's think that in our production environment, as I said, we have more than a thousand models, and that we are more than 10 people developing models every day there, in the same environment. Even if a typo should never reach our production environment, it may happen at some point! So, apparently, a single typo is going to prevent the execution of **every** model in our collection, and that does not sound OK at all. Someone not aware of this can make a great mess.

I searched for similar issues and, although found some (of course we are not the only ones having a big environment), not a single solution was pointed out.

Is there any obvious workaround here that we are missing? How do you undertake this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use CI (dbt cloud, github actions, etc.) to at least compile your models as part of the pull request process before merging with your main branch + deploying.